# Why is this HTML showing up as plain text in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been stumped on this for a while. I can't even find a similar scenario online. I have an HTML file from my professor that the browser interprets as plain text. Can someone tell me why?

Browser: Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0062)http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/helloworld/square.html -->
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="line-gutter-backdrop"></div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="1"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-comment">&lt;!--square.html--&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="2"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-doctype">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="3"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="4"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="5"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="6"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">vertex-shader</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">x-shader/x-vertex</span>"&gt;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="7"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> // GLSL vertex shader code</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="8"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> attribute vec4 vPosition; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="9"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="10"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> void main()</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="11"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> {</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="12"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> gl_Position = vPosition; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="13"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> }</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="14"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="15"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="16"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">fragment-shader</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">x-shader/x-fragment</span>"&gt;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="17"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> // GLSL fragment shader code</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="18"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> precision mediump float;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="19"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="20"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> void main()</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="21"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> {</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="22"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="23"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> }</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="24"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="25"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="26"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-comment">&lt;!--Include A/S WebGL support libraries--&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="27"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/webgl-utils.js">../Common/webgl-utils.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="28"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/initShaders.js">../Common/initShaders.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="29"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/MV.js">../Common/MV.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="30"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/webgl-debug.js">../Common/webgl-debug.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="31"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/helloworld/square.js">square.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="32"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="33"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;body&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="34"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;canvas <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">gl-canvas</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">width</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">512</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">height</span>="
          <span
            class="html-attribute-value">512</span>"&gt;</span>&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="35"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="36"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/canvas&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="37"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/body&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="38"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="39"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-end-of-file"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perhaps the server is sending with wrong content type?

Comment: How are you opening it? Is it sent from a server, or is it a local file? Maybe show a screenshot.

Comment: I'm loading it into a browser from a file named 'square.html' as is.

Comment: Please show a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This HTML isn't being interpreted as plain text: it's being interpreted as HTML.

It's just that the contents of your HTML include markup that has been escaped, such as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

**Update**

Is this the markup you want?

```
<!--square.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
// GLSL vertex shader code
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main()
{
gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
// GLSL fragment shader code
precision mediump float;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<!--Include A/S WebGL support libraries-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="square.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height=" 512">>
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I get around this?

Comment: YES! That looks great! What did you do?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can just copy from mine and it'll work for you.

Comment: My guess is you copied this markup from a website that showed your markup in tables. When you copied, you grabbed the underlying HTML.

Comment: Now I understand. I really think that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is kind of funny but make sure you edit and save the file with nodepad++ instead of notepad. As you see below i have created 3 files trying to run the html code on localhost, one.html and two.php where created via notepad, however three.html (which was created using notepad++) seem to work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be the missing doctype, which tells the browser what kind of document it's looking at. Add `<!doctype html>` at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a suggestion? If it's the latter, post it as a comment. If it's the former, then make it a statement instead of *try this*.

Comment: You’d want `<!DOCTYPE html>`, specifically, not the actual text `<!doctype>`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `<title>title</title>` in your header.

update

nothing is wrong with your code. it will actually output like and html code. Check your code line by line.

Comment: I check the html code and it's correct. nothing is wrong with your code.. try changing the table span to change the output..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0062)http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/helloworld/square.html -->
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="line-gutter-backdrop"></div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="1"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-comment">&lt;!--square.html--&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="2"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-doctype">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="3"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="4"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="5"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="6"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">vertex-shader</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">x-shader/x-vertex</span>"&gt;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="7"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> // GLSL vertex shader code</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="8"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> attribute vec4 vPosition; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="9"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="10"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> void main()</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="11"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> {</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="12"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> gl_Position = vPosition; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="13"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> }</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="14"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="15"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="16"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">fragment-shader</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">x-shader/x-fragment</span>"&gt;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="17"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> // GLSL fragment shader code</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="18"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> precision mediump float;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="19"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="20"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> void main()</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="21"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> {</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="22"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="23"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> }</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="24"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="25"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="26"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-comment">&lt;!--Include A/S WebGL support libraries--&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="27"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/webgl-utils.js">../Common/webgl-utils.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="28"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/initShaders.js">../Common/initShaders.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="29"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/MV.js">../Common/MV.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="30"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/Common/webgl-debug.js">../Common/webgl-debug.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="31"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;script <span class="html-attribute-name">type</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">text/javascript</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">src</span>="<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" target="_blank"
            href="http://csf11.acs.uwosh.edu/371-17/demos/helloworld/square.js">square.js</a>"&gt;</span><span class="html-tag">&lt;/script&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="32"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="33"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;body&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="34"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;canvas <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">gl-canvas</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">width</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">512</span>" <span class="html-attribute-name">height</span>="
          <span
            class="html-attribute-value">512</span>"&gt;</span>&gt;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="35"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="36"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/canvas&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="37"></td>
        <td class="line-content"> <span class="html-tag">&lt;/body&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="38"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/html&gt;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="line-number" value="39"></td>
        <td class="line-content"><span class="html-end-of-file"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have this same problem with my text.All my code shows up on the file.I just started coding so I am probably wrong but might be a bug on the text editor/software or you need a file extension like .html at the end of the file, those matter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29924303)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the content is not html type. I made a similar mistake and was wondering why it is showing as text. Check the content of the file, most probably it is not HTML or some html tags must be missing. Make sure that Doc type is explicitly mentioned as HTML type at the begining of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code. Not even the `<!DOCTYPE html>` has an effect on it. What displays in the browser is the content of the HTML code not the code itself.
The content that displays in the browser has been written using HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` which are used in place `<` and `>` respectively. These entities are used to prevent codes samples from running, instead of being displayed in the browser, especially when you want to explain some pieces of codes to someone and they need to see the codes as an example.
So, I think the person who wrote these code wanted to use it as a lecture for his/her students and maybe had not written the description yet.
Example:
If I write something like this code below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>This is how to write the form tag</p>
<!--Take note of this particular bolded code because that's where the point lies-->
<b>&lt;form&gt;&lt;/form&gt;</b>
</body>
</html>
```

The result will be something like this:

```
  This is how to write the form tag
  <form></form>
```

Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) to read more about HTML entities at w3schools.
This was the best I could explain as a beginner and using Stack Overflow platform to explain something for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was "UTF-8 With Bom" encoding of the file. I have converted the encoding to "UTF-8" and it works correctly now.