# show data from json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to show table from json but failed, what's wrong with this:

```
$nip=$_POST['nip']; 
$sql = "select satker,shift_description,nip  FROM jamkerja 
    inner join master_shift on master_shift.shiftno=jamkerja.shiftno 
    inner join tr_jamkerjahdr on jamkerja.id_jamkerja=tr_jamkerjahdr.id_jamkerja 
    inner join tr_jamkerjamember on tr_jamkerjamember.trno=tr_jamkerjahdr.trno 
    where nip='$nip' ";

$result = $con->query($sql);

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
print $data;
```

And this is the table:

```
$json = $data;
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach($json_decoded as $data12){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data12[satker].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data12[shift_description].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data12[nip].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `$json_decode`.Just loop through your array `$data`.

remove the :

```
$json = $data;
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);
```

and modify the foreach loop, adding the **table tag**.Also add **single qoutes** to your array indexes:

```
   echo '<table>';
    foreach($data as $data12){
                  echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$data12['satker'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data12['shift_description'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data12['nip'].'</td>';
              echo '</tr>';

        }

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: i get it

<table><tr><td>YAYASAN</td><td>Desc</td><td>001.115.14.04.2014</td></tr></table>


how show it for front end?

Comment: Tags are also displaying in the browser? Is that the actual value in your database?

Comment: I think you should include the complete hml format. `<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

Comment: the value is the correct value from the database, I want to display the record in the form of a table in the view

Comment: If your html tags are displaying as a text you can follow this question : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107855/why-is-this-html-showing-up-as-plain-text-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question.
But let me try to help you. I think your issue is around

```
$json = $data;
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);
```

json_decode() is not needed here, the $data that you are assigning to $json is a type array. With the code you shared, I don't see any need for Json, you should directly loop through your $data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did not find the record appearing as a table, I think there is something wrong with my code